# Typescript how to reference generic function alias type param in function that uses that alias

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to move entire generic function type out of its definition because it has many long type params.

This works:

```js
type DataFetcher = <T>(x: T) => T  // possibly many complicated type params and argument types

const fetchData: DataFetcher = x => x // always nice and simple, just `: DataFetcher`

const y = fetchData(3)
const z = fetchData<string>('smth')
```

However, sometimes I have to use type params not deducible from arguments, e.g.:

```js
type DataFetcher = <T, TT>(x: T) => T

const fetchData: DataFetcher = x => {
  callApi<TT>() // how to get TT while using DataFetcher?
  return x // when I hover on x (vs code) it correctly tells me it's of type T
}
```

My question is, can I both use `DataFetcher` and have access to `TT`? (so that I have as much type code moved out of function code as possible).

I tried:

```js
type DataFetcher = <T>(x: T) => T

const fetchData: DataFetcher = <TT>(x) => {  // x is of type any, not T from DataFetcher
  callApi<TT>()
  return x
}
```

which does not work (`DataFetcher` seems to be lost).

I know that I can just write:

```js
const fetchData = <T, TT>(x: T): T => {
  callApi<TT>()
  return x
}
```

But I have many functions with many long named T's in my codebase. I would like to, at least for my curiosity, see how it would look with all types extracted to separate file and main file containing only "JavaScript" logic.

I want to have nothing or only `TT` mentioned in `fetchData` definition and everything else extracted somehow out, so I can e.g. put it in separate file.
My question is, how do I make it happen?

NOTE: I'm new to Typescript, experienced in JavaScript and C++. I know that what I'm trying to do is probably unconventional, probably just have to let my eyes become accustomed to TS code.

Comment: A not great workaround,  if you have a parameter of type `TT` would be to use `typeof`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAxCwDGALCAnKBeKAHgBUAaKY4gPgAoAPALgvJCcoEp8qKAoAMwCuAOzTAAlgHshUNHAA2cgIJgxJWuwDeAXx5opAZ2BQ+qTPERNzyU1lwF6LEJzzcNPKDPlKVhUJAl8UCAg6u5Q2KgC2NJ0PDpAA

Comment: Typically you make the generics type parameters of the calling function as well. I realize you say that there may be a lot of type parameters and that implies undesirable duplication, but that is also *probably* telling you that you're trying to do too much in one function.

Comment: @JaredSmith yea, this function that returns a function that returns a function is a lambda context fueled network communication middleware injector factory with configurable request & response types. AFAIK it's in general a correct clean code and the structure also comes from APIs / frameworks we use. I'm new to this bleeding edge codebase with no discussion power or competences on what is correct and not (also regarding frameworks use) therefore I just want to play on the side with it and can locally use `typeof _TT` for my experiments although I intuitively feel TS could support such stuff.